# Why is RP-1 dyed red?

Tags: fuel, liquid-fuel

I was interested to learn that RP-1 is at least sometimes dyed to a red color.

What is the reason for doing this / what benefit does it give compared to leaving it the usual hydrocarbon clear-to-yellow? What makes it worth the impurity of the dyeing agent?

Comment: I would guess the colorant is a liquid solvable in petrol. No solid powder. The red color makes it easier to detect spills.

Comment: In Canada, agricultural diesel is dyed green, so if you buy it and use it in your diesel car, the cops can catch you by the green exhaust.  (Taxes are very different on the two types of diesel).  So maybe Rp-1 is died red so if you try using it in your rocket, with the agricultural licensed RP-1 you get ticketed once you reach orbit?  Hehe.

Comment: It could be a safety thing, so the correct "liquid" goes into the correct tank, in the same what different variants of petrol/gasoline are colored different so people know they are refueling with the correct fuel.

Comment: "red is fast"   https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RedOnesGoFaster?from=Main.TheRedOnesGoFaster

Answer (score 6):

RP 1 fuel was red dyed for a thermal stability experiment on JP-8 and RP-1 fuel of various ratios.

> High Reynolds Number Thermal Stability (HiReTS) testing device. There are several factors that set the HiReTS machine apart from other thermal stability tests.

The red dye of RP-1 was used to detect the various effects of parameters like temperature and flow rate ( from relative colouration of the fuel ).

> Standard RP has red dye. The ultra low formulations did not have red dye so one formulation was made with red dye to explore possible thermal stability changes.

[Link to the document from the experiment (PDF)](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20050204031.pdf)

Red dyed RP-1 was also used in another study on compositional variability under various thermophysical condition.

[Link to the article (PDF)](https://ws680.nist.gov/publication/get_pdf.cfm?pub_id=902380%22Red%20dye%20in%20RP-1%22)

I literally didn't find any other reason for using of a red dye.

Interestingly:

> In some countries it is required by law to dye a low-tax fuel to deter its use in applications intended for higher-taxed ones. Untaxed fuels are referred to as "dyed", while taxed ones are called "clear" or "white".

Also:

> The dyes used have to be soluble in the fuels they are added to and therefore in hydrocarbon-based nonpolar solvents ("solvent dyes"). Red dyes are often various diazo dyes, e.g., Solvent Red 19, Solvent Red 24, and Solvent Red 26. Anthraquinone dyes are used for green and blue shades, e.g., Solvent Green 33, Solvent Blue 35 and Solvent Blue 26.

[Fuel dyes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuel_dyes%22Wikipedia%20page%20on%20fuel%20dyes%22)

Comment: These experiments -- do they result in RP-1 *in general* being dyed?

Comment: @ikrase I was trying to find all or any reason for RP-1 being dyed red. There seems to be no other possible physical reason for the use.

Comment: @ikrase generally if you are caught driving with red dyed diesel, you might have to pay a hefty fine, cuz red dyed diesel is not taxed and shouldn't be used in automobiles. Dye is used to differentiate various colourless fuels...

Comment: I'm pretty sure by the time you're making RP-1, nobody's worried about the tax dodge. Not many people go out of their way to avoid paying taxes to the degree if paying a lot more.